# Web Worker FileReaderSync

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I am reading in files inside of a web worker. However, when I try to read the file I keep getting this error: Uncaught DataCloneError: An object could not be cloned. The only line of code that throws this error is the reader.readAsText(file). Can anyone explain why this is happening?

```
self.requestFileSystemSync = self.webkitRequestFileSystemSync || self.requestFileSystemSync;

try{
    var fs = requestFileSystemSync(TEMPORARY, 1024 * 1024);
}
catch (error) {onError(error);}

self.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    try{
        var path = e.data;            
        var file = fs.root.getFile(path, { create: false });
        var reader = new FileReaderSync();
        self.postMessage(reader.readAsText(file));
    }
    catch (error) { onError(error); }
});

function onError(error) { self.postMessage(error); }
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you solve it? I suspect that the error object is not allowed to be sent via 'postMessage'.